# Watson assistant api calls details

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

We have developed a watson assistant chatbot and integrated with client application. Now we want know how many times each user calling watson service from client application and its billing details per person.

I have enabled the user metrics option using below approach and Active users graph is updated with user count.
But I want to know the per user api calls details, I have checked in viewLogs(IMPROVE TAB) and  Usage tab in billing section and its not showing the per user api calls and billing details.
Please let me know where i can get the details of each user api calls details.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/logs.html#user_id

```
 "context" : {
  "metadata" : {
   "user_id": "{UserID}"
   }
   }
```

Comment: any one have idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no UI to show chats from a specific user. Instead, as described [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/logs.html#query_customer_id) you must use the REST API via curl to retrieve logs.

However when using user_id you cannot filter for a specific user. I have tried actually doing this but I am not able to retrieve logs for a specific user_id.

You can retrieve logs filtered for a customer_id and therefore I recommend you set both user_id and customer_id to the same value, and filter using customer_id.

To set customer_id do as the [SDK docs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#sending-request-headers) say and add a 'headers' object to the payload sent to Assistant with X-Watson-Metadata with value customer_id. For example in NodeJS:

```
payload.headers = {'X-Watson-Metadata': `customer_id=CUSTOMER_ID`}
assistant.message(payload, (err, data) => {
```

Then you can retrieve logs for a specific customer from Assistant by filtering by customer_id:

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:KEY" 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/WORKSPACE/logs?version=2018-09-20&filter=customer_id::CUSTOMER_ID'
```

Comment: thanks @DSeager for your answer, I will try with above options.

Comment: hi @dseager, I have tried with the above steps and got below result, its showing empty array for the customer.{"logs":[],"pagination":{}}

curl -X GET -u "apikey:key"  
 "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/workspaceid/logs?version=2018-09-20&filter=customer_id=customer5"   
tried below 1 got same 
curl -X GET -u "apikey:key" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/user_data?customer_id=customer5&version=2018-09-20"

var payload = { workspace_id: workspace,headers: {'X-Watson-Metadata': 'customer_id=customer5'},context: {metadata :{}},input: {}};

Comment: any one have idea about this ?